# Import a text file located in my local file system into javascript in ubuntu

Tags: javascript, html

I am using Linux and I want to import a text file present in /home/cloudera/File/myfile.text file into my html document containing javascript to display the contents of the text file in my web browser. I am new to this concept. Please help me by suggesting the possible ways how to do it. Also is .text file format in ubuntu same as .txt file format in windows?

Comment: JavaScript running in a web browser typically does not have access to the file system, so you can't do that.

Comment: Maybe [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) can help you.

Comment: So can I try embedding javascript with PHP? Actually I am trying to use google charts with javascript to build graphs and charts for the text file  containing the output from my another python file. So the flow is like my python file is giving some output which gets stored in a text file and that data I have to represent in charts and graphs to be displayed on a dashboard.

Comment: have you tried file:///user/home/cloudera/File/myfile.text as your url parameter